# Add a string after dirname and slash using preg_replace

Tags: php

If I have the following `PATH` as a `string`:

```
dirname/user folder/sample_file.png
```

How would I add the string `_trash` after the `dirname/user` folder in the PATH, so its result is:

```
dirname/user folder_trash/sample_file.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $path = "dirname/user folder/sample_file.png";

    echo $path = dirname($path) . "_trash/" . basename($path);

?>
```

Output:

```
dirname/user folder_trash/sample_file.png
```

**EDIT:**

You can search for the folder and then just replace it with the new one:

```
<?php

    $path = "dirname/user folder/another folder/sample_file.png";  

    $searchFolder = "/user folder/";
    $replaceFolder = "user folder_trash";

    echo $path = preg_replace($searchFolder, $replaceFolder, $path, 1); 

?>
```

Output:

```
dirname/user folder_trash/another folder/sample_file.png
```

**EDIT 2:**

IF the sting follows the same pattern every time this should work to change the second folder:

```
<?php

    $path = "dirname/user folder/another folder/another folder/sample_file.png";  

    $parts = explode("/", $path);
    $parts[1] = $parts[1] . "_trash";

    echo $path = implode("/", $parts);

?>
```

Output:

```
dirname/user folder_trash/another folder/another folder/sample_file.png
```

Comment: i already did that earlier. but if the path is dirname/user folder/another folder/sample_file.png or dirname/user folder/another folder/another folder/sample_file.png

Comment: Well u should have put that as a requirement in your question. So in short it's always the second folder that needs to be concatenated with `_trash`?

Comment: @StoledInk Updated my answer so now you can search for a folder and it gets replace with the new one

Comment: thats what i need sir DarkBee .

Comment: sir Rizier123 the user `user folder` is sample folder name only because there's a specific folder name for each user so i couldn't use the `$searchFolder = "/user folder/";`

Comment: @StoledInk Okay now i think i got it what you need

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

1. You also use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split string to items (using
   `count` function to get number of item).
2. Then modify each item. It up to you.
3. Finally, merge items to string by `string concatenation`